# Subset of a dataframe in pandas with error# duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select subset of my whole dataset based on several conditions:

1. Bankruptcy indicator shows 'Y'
2. Reason code shows '008'

This is head of my dataset looks like:

```
Charge-off Date         Accounting Charge-off Flag      Charge-off Principal        Pending Interest        Fee Pending     Total Account Charge-off Amount     Reason Code     Reason Desc                     Bankruptcy Indicator        Probate Indicator
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         9,058.76                   712.62               195.00                   9,966.38                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         7,483.89                   200.65               234.00                   7,918.54                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         2,160.71                   83.28                234.00                   2,477.99                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                                       P
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         11,048.93                  793.82               195.00                   12,037.75                    008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         11,017.25                  41.17                 0.00                    11,058.42                    001                 BANKRUPTCY                        Y               
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         2,306.96                   61.58                608.73                   2,977.27                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         3,623.08                   159.20               195.00                   3,977.28                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         2,795.51                   398.73               117.00                   3,311.24                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         5,694.77                   474.35               195.00                   6,364.12                     008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF                              
     31-OCT-19                        Y                         14,070.93                 1,273.81              273.00                   15,617.74                    008       CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF
```

Code:

```
df_mid = df_new[df_new['Bankruptcy Indicator'] == 'Y' and df_new['Reason Code']=='008']
```

However,it shows error with following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Bankruptcy Indicator'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-ddaf3ea29589> in <module>
----> 1 df_mid = df_new[df_new['Bankruptcy Indicator'] == 'Y' and df_new['Reason Code']=='008']

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Bankruptcy Indicator'
```

I initially thought it could be the column name doesn't appear correctly. But I tried to print out all columns, it works with type of string. So I'm so confused why it cannot subset of a dataframe.
Could anyone help?

Update: I've tried the code

```
df_mid = df_new[df_new['Bankruptcy Indicator'].eq('Y') & df_new['Reason Code'].eq('008')]
```

It still comes with the same error.

Comment: Can you list the column names? The column names got all mixed up here

Comment: I couldn't reconstruct the data

Comment: I updated it, thanks

Comment: I was able to construct the data and run the code without any error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the following command successfully:

```
df_mid = df_new[(df_new['Bankruptcy Indicator'] == 'Y') & (df_new['Reason Code']=='008')]
```

I have constructed the data like the following:

```
Charge-off Date;Accounting Charge-off Flag;Charge-off Principal;Pending Interest;Fee Pending;Total Account Charge-off Amount;Reason Code;Reason Desc;Bankruptcy Indicator;Probate Indicator
 31-OCT-19;Y;9,058.76;712.62;195.00;9,966.38;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;7,483.89;200.65;234.00;7,918.54;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;2,160.71;83.28;234.00;2,477.99;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;P
 31-OCT-19;Y;11,048.93;793.82;195.00;12,037.75;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;11,017.25;41.17;0.00;11,058.42;'001';BANKRUPTCY;Y;
 31-OCT-19;Y;2,306.96;61.58;608.73;2,977.27;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;3,623.08;159.20;195.00;3,977.28;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;2,795.51;398.73;117.00;3,311.24;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;5,694.77;474.35;195.00;6,364.12;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;
 31-OCT-19;Y;14,070.93;1,273.81;273.00;15,617.74;'008';CONTRACTUAL REGULAR CHARGE OFF;;

import pandas as pd
df_new = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')
```